# how to add margin without ruining responsiveness

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

so I have three cards in one row but they are all stuck together without margin  it looks ugly. I want there to be some margin between each card so I added margin but it ruins the responsiveness bootstrap provides. Thus I added padding only. Any help would be appreciated

```
<div class="row">
  {% for all_episode in episode %}
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 card" style="padding:20px">
      <a href="{% url 'episode_detail' slug=all_episode.slug %}">
        <img class="card-img-top" src='{{all_episode.image.url}}'>
      </a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">
          <a href="{% url 'episode_detail' slug=all_episode.slug %}">{{ all_episode.title }}</a>
        </h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ all_episode.story |slice:":100" }}...</p>
      </div>

      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
          <span class="h5">
            <a href="{% url 'series_detail' slug=all_episode.series.slug %}">{{ all_episode.series }}</a>
          </span> / 
          <span class="h6">
            <a href="{% url 'season_detail' slug=all_episode.season.slug %}">{{ all_episode.season }}
            </a>
          </span>
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap?

Comment: @shafik bootstrap4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just tweak the `card`

```
<div class="row">
    {% for all_episode in episode %}
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="card" style="padding:20px">
            <a href="{% url 'episode_detail' slug=all_episode.slug %}">
                <img class="card-img-top" src='{{all_episode.image.url}}'>
            </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">
          <a href="{% url 'episode_detail' slug=all_episode.slug %}">{{ all_episode.title }}</a>
        </h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ all_episode.story |slice:":100" }}...</p>
            </div>

            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">
          <span class="h5">
            <a href="{% url 'series_detail' slug=all_episode.series.slug %}">{{ all_episode.series }}</a>
          </span> / 
          <span class="h6">
            <a href="{% url 'season_detail' slug=all_episode.season.slug %}">{{ all_episode.season }}
            </a>
          </span>
        </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but with this approach I don't get the border the bootstrap card provides. so now the card doesnt have the border

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap Card Deck all cards will be in a row and responsive.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-decks